# Scrapy: How to populate an item with data from two websites

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to collect an item's data from 2 different websites.

It should work as follows:

1. parse_website_1 fetches a persons name from website_1 and populates
   the item
2. parse_website_1 yields a request for parse_website_2
3. parse_website_2 parses website_2, collects the persons hair-color, based on the person name which was scraped from website_1 and populates the item
4. parse_website_2 loads the item

Would this be in the right direction, given that the item is defined in `items.py`:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import MyItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "myspider" 

    def __init__(self):
        self.item = ItemLoader(item=MyItem(), response=response)  

    def start_requests(self):
        scrapy.Request(url="http://website_1.com", callback=self.parse_website_1)

    def parse_website_1(self, response):   
        name = response.xpath('//div[@class="name"]/text()').extract_first()
        self.item.add_value("name", name)
        website_2_path = "http://website_2.com/" + name 
        yield scrapy.Request(url=website_2_path, callback=self.parse_website_2)

    def parse_website_2(self, response):
        self.item.add_xpath("hair_color", '//div[@class="hair_color"]')
        yield self.item.load_item()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is right, but the implementation is not correct in that you are trying to pass data between consecutive requests using an instance attribute (`self.item`). Scrapy requests are asynchronous so it would not work as expected.

The correct way how to do it is outlined in Scrapy [FAQ](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments). Pass the partial item data to consecutive request using `Request`'s `meta` attribute where you obtain it using `Response`'s `meta` attribute, add some more data and finally yield the item. Here's the adapted code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import MyItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider" 

    def start_requests(self):
        scrapy.Request(url="http://website_1.com", callback=self.parse_website_1)

    def parse_website_1(self, response):   
        item = ItemLoader(item=MyItem(), response=response)
        name = response.xpath('//div[@class="name"]/text()').extract_first()
        item.add_value("name", name)
        website_2_path = "http://website_1.com/" + name 
        yield scrapy.Request(url=website_2_path, callback=self.parse_website_2, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_website_2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item.add_xpath("hair_color", '//div[@class="hair_color"]')
        yield item.load_item()
```